# OneSignal, Ionic 4 - getPermissionSubscriptionState() not being called unless app restarts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, onesignal

the issue I am having is that when using OneSignal for my push notifications the method `.getPermissionSubscriptionState()` is not being called unless on refresh. I created a [github](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/587) issue and waiting for a reply from them or someone else who has had this issue and what workaround they found for it.
here it is.

#### app.component.ts

```js
    public initializeApp(): void {
      this.platform.ready().then((): void => {
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
        this.authService.authState.subscribe(
          async (state: boolean): Promise<void> => {
            if (state) {
              if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
                this.setupPush();
              }
              await this.router.navigate(['home']);
            } else {
              await this.router.navigate(['login-register']);
            }
          },
        );
      });
    }

    private setupPush(): void {
      console.log('setup Push called'); // <-- seen in the console
      const conn = new Connections();
      this.oneSignal.startInit(conn.oneSignalAppData.osAppId, conn.oneSignalAppData.googleProjectNumber);
      this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None);

      console.log('before get permission sub state'); // <-- seen in the console
      this.oneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState().then(information => {
        console.log('information', information); // <-- NOT seen in the console
        this.userService.setOsData = information; // setting to undefined
        this.authService.setPushToken = information.subscriptionStatus.userId; // undefined
      });

      // Notification was received in foreground
      this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data from push when open', data); // subscribed successfully, receive data
      });
    // Notification was received while app was closed(not in background or foreground)
    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((data: any): void => {
        console.log('data when closed from push', data); // subscribed effectively
        this.notification.notificationController(notificationPayload);
      });
      this.oneSignal.endInit();
    }
```

the order doesn't matter, as I've tried placing it in a separate function and calling it later, if it was an issue of asynchrony, which it doesn't appear to be. However, without fail if the app is restarted then the method in question is being called and I see the information I need.

Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/587): you need to call those *after* `oneSignal.endInit()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem i found also with my code is that the method such as getPermissionSubscriptionState() need to be called AFTER OneSignal.endInit(), what i did is i called getPermissionSubscriptionState() Method in Settimeout and it worked.